# How create an R function that take a FUN as parameter

Tags: r, function, parameters

To extend the usability of a R function, we need to pass an argument of type function (FUN), Could you please demonstrate how to declare a function parameter inside in another function and how to call it. Like

```
MyOperation <- function(x, y, FUN){
    int sum <- x+y
    if (!missing(FUN)) sum<-FUN(sum)}
    return sum
}

Res <- MyOperation(x=1, y=2, FUN=function(n){...})
```

Comment: You seem to be mixing R code with another language...for instance in R, we don't declare the variable type `int`. R _knows_ that you're creating a integer variable when the inputs are integers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't declare variables in R. Also you can specify a default value right in the formal argument list.  You don't need to use `missing` in this situation.

This runs `FUN(x + y)` or returns `x+y` if `FUN` is not specified.

```
myOp2 <- function(x, y, FUN = identity) FUN(x + y)

myOp2(1, 2)
## [1] 3

myOp2(1, 3, sqrt)
## [1] 2
```

One enhancement might be to allow the function to be specified either as a function or as a character string:

```
myOp2a <- function(x, y, FUN = identity) {
    FUN <- match.fun(FUN)
    FUN(x + y)
}

myOp2a(1, 3, "sqrt")
## [1] 2

myOp2a(1, 3, sqrt)
## [1] 2
```

This sums `x` and `y` if `FUN` is not specified; otherwise, it runs `FUN` with the arguments `x` and `y`.

```
myOp3 <- function(x, y, FUN = sum) FUN(x, y)

myOp3(1, 2)   
## [1] 3

myOp3(1, 2, min)
## [1] 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have some basic R syntax problems there. There's no `int` in R, your function closing bracket was in the wrong place, `return()` is a function in R -- not a keyword. Check out

```
MyOperation<-function(x,y,FUN){
  sum <- x+y
  if (!missing(FUN)) sum<-FUN(sum)
  return(sum)
}

MyOperation(x=1,y=2)
# [1] 3 
MyOperation(x=1,y=2,FUN=function(n){n+100})
# [1] 103
```